# regexp and sed find block of string in multiline block untill it end with space

Tags: regex, string, sed, comments, multilinestring

I try to capture those blocks of strings and comment on them using regexp and sed. Each block separated with space:

```
some text here 
some text here 

AppServer1:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
   
some text here 
some text here 

AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here 
some text here
```

I try with this regexp:

```
sed E '/./{H;1h;$!d} ; x ; s/[^\$AppServer1](AppServer1)/#\1/gi'
```

but the result is:

```
 #AppServer1:
      name: $#{AppServer1.name}
      ip: $#{AppServer1.ip}
```

What am I missing here to comment the full string to be as below?

```
#AppServer1:
#      name: ${AppServer1.name}
#      ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu-sed`, you can do this:

```sh
sed '/^AppServer1/I{:a; /^[[:blank:]]*$/!{s/.*/#&/; n; ba;} }' file

some text here
some text here

#AppServer1:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here

AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here
```

**Details:**

- `/^AppServer1/I`: Search for `AppServer1` case insensitive
- `{`: Block start

  - `:a`: Make label `a`
  - `/^[[:blank:]]*$/!` If a line is not a blank line
  - `{s/.*/#&/; n; ba;}`: Prepend each line with `#`, read next line and goto label `a`
- `}`: Block end

---

Using `awk` you can do this:

```sh
awk '/^AppServer1/ {b=1} b && !NF {b=0} b {$0 = "#" $0} 1' file

some text here
some text here

#AppServer1:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here

AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here
```

Comment: Thanks but its abit problematic to use awk , in my case ...

Comment: I have provided a sed solution as well

Comment: Thank! how do i make the AppServer1 to be not case sensetive in the regexp ?

Comment: also can you please explain what the sed expretion is doing ?

Comment: ok check updated answer for explanation and case ignore match

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740324/sed-regexp-find-block-of-string-in-multiline-block-and-remove-string-untill-it-e

Comment: sure, let me check it now.

Comment: can you please check this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793203/sed-regexp-add-xml-comment-around-xml-block/68795386#68795386

Answer (score 2):

A simpler `sed` solution might be this, if you're ok with having the final empty line commented too:

```sh
sed '/^AppServer1:/,/^[[:space:]]*$/s/^/# /' lines.txt
```

```
some text here
some text here

# AppServer1:
#   name: ${AppServer1.name}
#   ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
# 
some text here
some text here

AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here
```

It uses a `sed` range pattern, denoted by a comma (`,`). The start of the range is `/^AppServer1:/`, i.e., any line that starts (`^`) with `AppServer1:`. The end of the range is an empty line or one that contains only whitespace characters: `/^[[:space:]]*$/`, where `^`: start of line; `[[:space:]]*`: zero or more (`*`) whitespace characters (`[[:space:]]`); `$`: end of line.

Next comes the [s]ubstitution command — `s/^/# /` — which substitutes the start of the line `^` with the sequence `#`  on all lines within the matched range (inclusive end).

If you want a case-insensitive match, you need GNU `sed`. In that case you can add the `I` flag to the start-of-range pattern. This flag is not available on macOS `sed`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines in your input that look empty truly are empty, you can do this using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/^AppServer1:/{gsub(/^|\n/,"&#")} 1' file
some text here
some text here

#AppServer1:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here

AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here
```