# sed regexp find block of string in multiline block and remove string untill it end with space

Tags: regex, sed

I try to capture those blocks of strings and remove comment on them using regexp and sed. Each block separated with space

```
some text here 
some text here 

# AppServer1:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
   
some text here 
some text here 

# AppServer2:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here 
some text here
```

I try with this regexp:

```
sed '/^AppServer1/I{:a; /^[[:blank:]]*$/!{s/.*#.*/&/; n; ba;} }' file
```

but it does not affect the string.

What am I missing here to uncomment the full string to be:

```
AppServer1:
      name: ${AppServer1.name}
      ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
```

### Update

After implementing @anubhava solution, I notice that if the string is notice the extra "#" in between the blocks:

```
some text here 
some text here 

# AppServer1:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
#   
# AppServer2:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here 
some text here
```

And I like to remove only the comments of "AppServer1:", it will remove the comments also from "AppServer2:", and it will look like this:

```
AppServer1:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
   
 AppServer2:
  name: ${AppServer1.name}
  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
```

This can happen if someone accidentally sets extra "#". How can I add this OR condition in the regexp, so if it's blank line OR 1 # in the line don't continue to uncomment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this `gnu-sed` that doesn't require a blank line after commented lines that start with `/# AppServer1/`:

```sh
sed -E '/^#[[:blank:]]*AppServer1:/I, /^#?[[:blank:]]*$|^($|[^#])/ s/#[[:blank:]]?//' file

some text here
some text here

AppServer1:
 name: ${AppServer1.name}
 ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

# AppServer2:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}

some text here
some text here
```

**Details:**

- `/^#[[:blank:]]*AppServer1:/I`: Start range from a line that starts with `#` followed by 0 or more spaces and `AppServer1:` (ignore case)
- `,/^#?[[:blank:]]*$|^($|[^#])/`: Range end with a line that just has `#` OR a line that doesn't have `#` at line start
- `s/#[[:blank:]]?//`: Removes first `#` followed by an optional space

Comment: it will uncomment also the AppServer2 which is not good

Comment: No it won't. I have included generated output also in answer

Comment: sorry sorry only if the file is like this : 
#AppServer1:
# name: ${AppServer1.name}
# ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
#
# AppServer2:
#  name: ${AppServer1.name}
#  ip: ${AppServer1.ip}
note the extra "#" in between

Comment: can i add some kind of OR this do not work : 
'/#[[:blank:]]*AppServer1/I, /[^[[:blank:]]*|#]$/ { s/.*#// }'

Comment: nono not more then one , just the one that contain the name for example :AppServer1
but i found out that if by some mistake someone set after the block single "#" 
it comment the block after , which i want to avoid

Comment: It is difficult to understand multi line text from comments. Can you edit question and show this problematic input text in question

Answer (score 2):

I see at least a couple of issues:

- `/^AppServer1/` will match only from start of line, but you are looking for commented blocks. Remove `^` from the regexp to match anywhere in the line, or perhaps `/#[[:blank:]]*AppServer1/` would suit you better
- `s/.*#.*/&/` doesn't do anything to change the line. Whatever is matched is used again as the replacement. `s/.*#//` will remove everything from start of the line till the last occurrence of `#`

You can also use address range instead of building a loop manually:

```sh
sed '/#[[:blank:]]*AppServer1/I, /^[[:blank:]]*$/ { s/.*#// }'
```