# sed regexp add xml comment around xml block

Tags: xml, sed, comments

i have this xml which i like to comment by string
this is my xml ( part of it )

```
<subsystem
    xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app1" pool-name="app1" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false">
            <test1></test1>
            <test2></test2>
        </datasource>
         
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app2" pool-name="app2" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false"><test1></test1><test2></test2></datasource>
             
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

i tried this sed regexp but was able to capture only the first <datasource tag
this is what i tried :

```
sed -E '/./{H;1h;$!d} ; x ; s/(<datasource.*app1*)/ <!--\n\1-->/gi'
```

based on [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) section 6.2

i like to capture the and put it in comment so it will look like this

```
<subsystem
    xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
<!--
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app1" pool-name="app1" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false">
            <test1></test1>
            <test2></test2>
        </datasource>
-->

         
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app2" pool-name="app2" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false"><test1></test1><test2></test2></datasource>
             
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

**UPDATE**
please dont close the question
i dont have xml tools on my host only basic linux tools

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: i have no xml in my host and can't install one , sed is what i have

Comment: please dont close the question as i dont have xml tool on my host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont have xml tools on my host only basic linux tools

In the absence of XML parsing tools, you can use this basic `sed` command to comment out a block as you want. Please bear in mind that this will not be a robust solution as offered by tools like `xmllint`.

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed '/<datasource [^>]*app1/,/<\/datasource>/ {s/<datasource /<!--\n\t&/; s~</datasource>~&\n\t-->~;}' file.xml

<subsystem
    xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
    <!--
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app1" pool-name="app1" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false">
            <test1></test1>
            <test2></test2>
        </datasource>
    -->

            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/app2" pool-name="app2" enabled="true"
                            use-ccm="false"><test1></test1><test2></test2></datasource>

    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

**Explanation:**

- `/<datasource [^>]*app1/`: Match range start from `<datasource` tag that has text `app1` in it somewhere
- `,/<\/datasource>/`: range end with closing `</datasource>` tag.
- `{`: Start action block

  - `s/<datasource /<!--\n\t&/;`: Prepend opening `<datasource` tag with a comment start line `<!--`
  - `s~</datasource>~&\n\t-->~;`: Append closing `</datasource>` with comment closing line `-->`
- `}`: End action block

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples in `awk` please try following.

```
awk '
/<datasource.*pool-name="app1"/{ found=1 }
found{
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0
}
/<\/datasource>/ && found{
  print "<!--" ORS value ORS "-->"
  value=found=""
  next
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/<datasource.*pool-name="app1"/{ found=1 }    ##Checking if line contains <datasource till pool-name="app1" then set found to 1 here.
found{                                        ##Checking if found is set then do following.
  value=(value?value ORS:"")$0                ##Creating value which has current line and keep concatenating its value to it.
}
/<\/datasource>/ && found{                    ##If line contains </datasource> and found is set then do following.
  print "<!--" ORS value ORS "-->"            ##Printing comments section before and after value.
  value=found=""                              ##Nullifying value and found here.
  next                                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                                             ##Printing current line here.
'  Input_file
```